# What goes better with "first" -- "second" or "secondly"?

Tags: word-choice

Say you're making an argument that has two parts:

> Why did such and so happen?  First, bla bla.  Second, bla-pity bla bla bla.

I'm thinking "secondly" would sound better.  But if I use "secondly," do I have to use "firstly" -- which sounds so -- yuck.

The tone of the piece of writing is medium formal.  I mean, it's formal, but not formal at the level of a brief submitted to the Supreme Court.

Comment: 'Second' is fine, in my opinion. If you want, you could try: 'Also', 'In addition', 'On the other hand', 'One must not forget/ignore'...

Comment: @marcellothearcane - thanks, I like second better than also.  (I tend to overuse "also.")

Comment: @andrewleach - I don't know whether you'll be able to see this comment, but my question is different from the one you found.  That person wanted to know if he could have a list of one item.  I have a list of two items, and I wonder if *first* and *secondly* can go together, or if they have to match (first and second; firstly and secondly).

Comment: How about [a different one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273525/first-secondly-c) then? I am convinced this question is answered elsewhere already. (And a duplicate simply points to you to the answer to your question; it doesn't mean that the *question* is exactly the same)

Comment: @AndrewLeach - The question looks quite different; if you think a particular answer gives me what I need, how 'bout you link to the answer? // Is there a tldr for Sven's comprehensive treatise?

Comment: @JEL - Isn't that the same as what Andrew found?

Comment: First can be used as shorthand for 'first of all' which basically means *firstly* -- so it's not illogical to state your *first* point and follow it up with *either 'second' or 'secondly'* as you like it -- if you prefer to use 'first' and 'secondly' there is nothing wrong with it even for medium formal usage, methinks: not least because the 2 words will be separated by some pertinent observation and will not be read together as 'first, secondly, etc' -- so go ahead and use it! Example: *First, this is a linguist's website. Secondly, learners have ELL.* [I agree that 'firstly' sounds so (...)]

Comment: @EnglishStudent - My deadline really appreciates your comment.  Even better if you make it an answer, so voting results can give me more confidence in using *first* with *secondly*.  I personally think that the argument you presented is pretty good back-up for a question that is all about style.

Comment: Thank you. As long as you got some useful input, I am very satisfied; and shall consider writing it as an answer only later, because many persons here expect even common-sense statements like these, if posted as an answer, to be supported by references, which I cannot (be bothered to) look for or supply in this particular case. What is absolutely certain is that *you can't go wrong with 'first' and 'secondly' because it's a matter of style!*

Answer (score 0):

*First* is necessarily followed by *second*.

*Secondly* necessarily follows *firstly*, however 'yuck' that might sound.

I suspect *firstly/secondly* is both more formally correct and less modern and  *first/second* is less formal and more modern but I won't bet on either…

Comment: Oh, come on, Guys! How could anyone doubt what I said, let alone down it?

Even if I were wholly wrong I still think anonymous downing shouldn't be alllowed.

Comment: You should worry if you never are the target of the drive-by downvoter.  :)

Comment: Point taken, ab2, and I still think anonymous downing shouldn't be allowed

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin by 'anonymous downing not to be allowed', do you just want the downvoter to be identified? I have taken exception a couple of times not to 'anonymous' downvoting as such, but the fact that the anonymous downvoter did not specify the reason for the downvote. Of course leaving a comment as to the reason would immediately identify the downvoter at present, but we could possibly include a stipulation to downvoting that makes compulsory the leaving of an optionally  anonymous comment specifying the reason 4 DV. Would you like to invite discussion by framing this as a meta question?

Comment: @aparente001 your very pertinent point adds an interesting dimension to this topic. I forgot an explanatory comment might be rude, but I should prefer even a nasty comment explaining the reason for downvoting, and I daresay Robbie G would as well! There could also be a provision to protect the identity of the downvoter while explaining the reason for the DV.      If the reason given does not convince us we shall ignore it. If the comment is offensive we shall flag it. The anonymous downvote is not at all helpful because it offers no feedback and gives us no suggestion to help improve the post.

Comment: @aparente001 I also believe that if downvoters were required to provide at least an 'anonymous reason' for downvotes (same for upvotes) it would discourage thoughtless and reckless up- and down-voting, although the reputation points would not build up at quite the same rapid rate! I have seen so many mediocre posts including outright wrong answers upvoted for no good reason --some of mine included-- and earning 10 points multiple times for the lucky member. So let users explain the reason for upvoting as well!

Comment: Gosh, English Student; you put in a lot of thought. I agree the reason is more important than the identity, and there could be an option to leave anonymous explanations.
Would you like to invite discussion by framing this as a meta question?
You’re right: I, too, would prefer a rude explanatory comment to none and there could easily be a provision to protect the identity of the downvoter while explaining the reason for the DV.
the unexplained downvote is as useful as a poke in the eye: pure pain with no clear purpose.
Yes, let users explain the reason for down- or upvoting
Off to meta